# Start running Jenkins jobs simultaneously in sync

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to start running Jenkins jobs **simultaneously** in such way that in case when some of the configurations couldn't be started "parent" job waits until all of them could be initiated in sync?

I've already checked [Matrix Project](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin) and [Pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) plug-ins for starting jobs in parallel, but it seems both of them are missing possibility to freeze execution until all configuration could be started at the same time.

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you mean by _freeze execution until all configuration could be started at the same time_? You mean you want all branches to start simultaneously, waiting for all executor slots to be available at once? Why?

Comment: @JesseGlick I would like to test a distributed system which would be either running across several nodes or executors. To do so I would like to have Jenkins in control of builds and enforcing timeout threshold in case of deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Pipeline you could do something like (untested)

```
def count = 0
parallel a: {
  node {
    count++
    waitUntil {count == 3}
    sh 'make CONFIG=a'
  }
}, b: {
  node {
    count++
    waitUntil {count == 3}
    sh 'make CONFIG=b'
  }
}, c: {
  node {
    count++
    waitUntil {count == 3}
    sh 'make CONFIG=c'
  }
}
```

It is not generally a good idea, since you can effectively deadlock waiting for all three nodes to be locked simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your suggestion I've written a simple pipeline [script](https://github.com/luka5z/jenkinsci-workflow-plugin-examples/blob/master/jobs/parallel-waituntil.groovy). It not only waits until all nodes will be available, but also wraps it around timeout section.

Comment: Nice. Tips: no need to import `FlowInterruptedException` when `catch`ing plain Java `InterruptedException` would probably suffice; and can probably replace `manager.build.doStop()` (i.e., `currentBuild.rawBuild.doStop()`) with sandbox-friendly `throw e`, especially if you add `failFast: true` to the `parallel` step.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin) might help you out.